# Why is an A element often used instead of a BUTTON for web design?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Is there any particular reason why people use the A tag to mimic a BUTTON in HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Because it works for a specific problem? Maybe you should some more detailed example where you see this used and why you think a button would work the same? Most likely they just want a link activated and a A tag does this 'natively' while for a button to do this you would have to write some js code.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit on the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange...?  Are you asking about from the users' perspective or from a programming perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons is that you can't `href` a button, which also means that the browser won't show at the bottom the target link on mouse hover.

Another reason is that button requires to be embedded in a `form`, as well as, at least in XHTML 1.1, in a `div`. This means lots of markup for a simple button.

Unless the button leads to an action which changes state (which logically requires a POST), why would anyone use a button instead of a link?

IF you have a set of actions, some being symbolized by buttons (for example "Save changes" and "Revert to previous state"), and some other being logically simple links (for example "Display details" which leads to a different page which shows a detailed view of a modified item), UX-wise, it would be more intuitive for the user to have an uniform view, i.e. having three items which look like buttons, instead of two buttons and a link. This doesn't mean that you should bend your markup to adjust it to the presentation.

Comment: So this is why many js UI frameworks mimic the button functionality with an "A" in order to be flexible and not all buttons need to be in a form, for example the "buttons" on a tool bar or tab. Am I correct in this conclusion?

Comment: @gevik: I gave you a few reasons based on my own experience. I haven't contributed to any UI frameworks, so I don't know if their reasons are the same.